# litelement - how to compute style based on property or attribute values

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, lit-element

I'm following the LitElement guide [here](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles) but can't seem to get my custom element's style values calculated based on it's attribute.

I want my element to be written in one of following ways:

```html
<my-element data="some values" darkmode></my-element>
<my-element data="some values"></my-element>
```

I want to style the element's background and text colour depending on whether `dardmode` attribute is set or not.

In my LitElement class, I created a corresponding property and also initialized it. But, in the static style, `this.darkMode` is always returning `false`. I think I'm missing something here but not sure what:

```
class MyElement extends LitElement {

    static get properties() {
        return {
            data:    { type: String },
            darkMode:   { type: Boolean }
        };
    }

    static get styles() {
        const background_color = this.darkMode ? css`#000` : css`#fff` ;
        const text_color = this.darkMode ? css`#fff` : css`#333333`;

        return [
            css`
            :host {
                display: block;
            }
            .data-container {
                font-family: "Roboto",-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
                text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
                background-color: ${background_color} !important;
                color: ${text_color} !important;
            }`
       ];

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.data = "";
        this.darkMode = false;
    }

    render() {
        return html`
           <div class="data-container">
               <p>${this.data}</p>
           </div>
        `;
    }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
static get styles() {
  const background_color = this.darkMode ? css`#000` : css`#fff` ;
  // ...
```

…`styles` is a static method, so within it `this` refers to the MyElement class itself, so `this.darkMode` is the `darkMode` property of MyElement and not the `darkMode` property of any instance of MyElement. Of course, `MyElement.darkMode` is always `undefined`, so you always get the "light" styles.

A different and more maintainable approach would be to "reflect" the `darkMode` property to an attribute of the element with the `reflect: true` option and then use the CSS attribute selector `[dark-mode]` to override the "light" styles, e.g.:

```css
.data-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
}
:host([dark-mode]) .data-container {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

You can see this working in the below snippet:

```js
const { LitElement, css, html } = litElement;

class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      data: { type: String },
      darkMode: {
        type: Boolean,
        reflect: true,
        attribute: 'dark-mode',
      },
    };
  }

  static get styles() {
    return css `
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
      .data-container {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #333;
      }
      :host([dark-mode]) .data-container {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
      }
    `;
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.data = "";
    this.darkMode = false;
  }

  render() {
    return html `
      <div class="data-container">
        <p>${this.data}</p>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/lit-element@2.2.1"></script>

<my-element data="some dark values" dark-mode></my-element>
<my-element data="some light values"></my-element>
```

Comment: Nice answer, I'll add that he can also use css variables to achieve the same result without depending on host level styles if he wanted

Comment: Thanks @jordan-running for the explanation and the sample test. I'm new to webcomponent and still learning all of these. In the meantime, I handled it slightly differently by echoing `${this.darkmode ? 'dark' : 'light'}` directly in the render method's `<div>` element's classname. Then I have a separate classname for the div, which is use for styling. Followed the guide from here: https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/try/style

Comment: This answer ain't correct. :host([dark-mode]) should be :host([darkmode]) currently it is working cause you are passing dark-mode manually. But if you dont pass and only set through constructor, then it will not be black bg. attribute: "dark-mode" is required if you wanna use former selector