# Litelement component styling - :host with attributes or classes

Tags: css, css-selectors, attributes, styles, lit-element

I'm developing web components with lit-element (Typescript). I have a button represented on HTML like this:

```
<wc-btn class="class1" attribute1></wc-btn>
```

**attribute1** is defined as reflect:

```
@property({ type: Boolean, reflect: true })
public attribute1: Boolean = false;
```

The question is if I could mix at my styles the class with the attribute on something like this:

```
:host([attribute1] .class1) {}

or 

:host([attribute1]) .class1 {}
```

or whatever. I've seen this question and doesn't work for me:

[litelement - how to compute style based on property or attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314408/litelement-how-to-compute-style-based-on-property-or-attribute-values)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can style controls within your shadow DOM, so:

```css
:host([attribute1]) .class1 {}
```

Will apply to anything with `class1` *inside* the shadow DOM of the component with `[attribute1]`.

This won't cascade to light DOM or into sub-components, but you can style based on the reflected boolean attribute.

Meanwhile:

```css
:host([attribute1].class1) {}
```

Would apply to the host only when it has both class `class1` and `[attribute1]`.